# Is there a way to execute only some packages in SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a use case where I have a lot of services running in the same code base but they are in different packages. So, whenever I start SpringBoot all those services start. Is there a way I can specify SpringBoot to start the code in a particular package?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand why you want to handle the scope of execution like that. What do you really try to achieve?

Comment: If you want to manipulate the whole bootstrapping process, e.g. which auto configurations are applied, which classes and configs are used; you could have a look at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/tree/master/spring-cloud-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/bootstrap 
For simpler use cases you can use profiles or a custom https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use component scan annotation in main class, which will scan only the packages mentioned

```
 @ComponentScan(basePackages = "name of specific package")
```